# Android - ошибка при импорте проекта

Tags: project, eclipse, android, java, aide

Создал проект в AIDE, потом пришла пора перенести его в Eclipse. Перенёс папку с проектом, но при его открытии выдаёт ошибку: `Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead.`
Как это исправить? Раньше проекты импортировались нормально, а тут...

P.S. большая просьба не посылать в гугл, это же форум взаимной помощи, а не посылания людей юзать поисковик)

Answer (score 3):

Написано же черным по белому, что компилятор должен быть JDK 6... Установите JDK 6 и не майтесь всякими компатибилити флажками.

В документации по требованиям написано:

> JDK 6 (JRE alone is not sufficient)

Comment: Тогда почему другой проект из AIDE при импорте в Eclipse не выдаёт ошибку? Может быть дело в .classpath?

Comment: Да хз... советую не тратить время на глупости. Может быть для классов используемых в другом конкретном проекте генерируется объектный код совместимый с JDK 6, может быть вы не очистили выходной каталог, да мало ли еще какие причины. Все может быть. Но самое главное что это никому неинтересно.

Comment: Ну раз это нникому нееинтересно, то я закрываю вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

На стеке такое обсуждалось: [Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea).

[Первая ссылка](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Android+requires+compiler+compliance+level+5.0+or+6.0.+Found+'1.7'+instead&oq=Android+requires+compiler+compliance+level+5.0+or+6.0.+Found+'1.7'+instead&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64l2.408j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) по поиску кстати. Так что по хорошему надо Вас либо туда послать, либо научить пользоваться. Не потому что мы злые, а потому что это Вам поможет в жизни :-)

Comment: То, что там написано, не помогает.Именно я поэтому и просил не посылать меня в гугл, потому что я его уже перерыл

Comment: Ну тогда приведите больше симптомов и что конкретно вы делаете

Comment: `Could not write file: D:\My Box Files\EclipseAndroidWorkSpace\FeatherPlayer\.classpath.`
Что делал: сжал папку с проектом, перенёс и распаковал её на компьютере, загружаю в Eclipse, а там выводит ошибку.

Comment: Так а почему не может записать файл, не выясняли?